# Negative limit offset in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I'm creating a high score server and one of the needed features is being able to retrieve high scores around the users current score. I currently have the following:

```
SELECT * FROM highscores 
WHERE score >= ( SELECT score FROM highscores WHERE userID = someID ) 
ORDER BY score, updated ASC 
LIMIT -9, 19
```

The only problem here is that the offset parameter of LIMIT can't be negative, otherwise I believe this would work dandy. So in conclusion, is there any trick / way to supply a negative offset to the LIMIT offset, or is there perhaps a better way to about this entirely?

Comment: Not sure why you need to use negative offset, can you just flip the ordering from ASC to DESC ?

Comment: Then I get the same problem but on the other end. Lets say the player is rank 345 on the leader board, the rank is implicit from the ORDER BY score, updated ( prioritizing older scores ). We then need to retrieve the rows 345-9 - 345+9, I can't seem to find a way to achieve this by the LIMIT clause, as now matter how I sort I seem to need a negative offset.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can either do a real pain in the butt single select query, or just do this:

```
(SELECT * FROM highscores 
WHERE score <= ( SELECT score FROM highscores WHERE userID = someID ) 
ORDER BY score, updated ASC 
LIMIT 9)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM highscores 
WHERE score = ( SELECT score FROM highscores WHERE userID = someID ))
UNION 
(SELECT * FROM highscores 
WHERE score >= ( SELECT score FROM highscores WHERE userID = someID ) 
ORDER BY score, updated ASC
LIMIT 9)
```

I threw in a piece to grab the indicated user's score so it's in the middle of the list. Optional if you need it. Also, don't use SELECT *, use specific fields. Clarity is always preferable, and performance wise, * sucks.

Comment: This gets me on the track but I get the following problem: lets say I have 100 scores and I'm trying to get the 9 scores on either side of the 50th high score. So I want scores 40-60. This code above returns 1-10 and 50-60. Help?

Comment: @themerlinproject use ORDER BY score DESC, updated ASC in the first statement