# SQL syntax error in pagination query

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to make pagination in my jsp page. But I didn't get data from Database. I got an error "**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-10, 5' at line 1**".

I didn't understand what's wrong. would you please check my code and help me to solve the problem?

BooksInfo.java

```
package com.sreejonee.books;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class BooksInfo {
private int book_id;
private String bookName;
private String filename;
private String writerName;
private String book_details;
private Timestamp date_time;
private int rating;
private int parentscat_id;
private String parentscat_name;
private String thumCoverImag;
private String filePath;


public int getBook_id() {
     return book_id;
}
public void setBook_id(int book_id) {
     this.book_id = book_id;
}
public String getBookName() {
    return bookName;
}
public void setBookName(String bookName) {
    this.bookName = bookName;
}
public String getFilename() {
    return filename;
}
public void setFilename(String filename) {
    this.filename = filename;
}
public String getWriterName() {
    return writerName;
}
public void setWriterName(String writerName) {
    this.writerName = writerName;
}
public String getBook_details() {
    return book_details;
}
public void setBook_details(String book_details) {
    this.book_details = book_details;
}
public Timestamp getDate_time() {
    return date_time;
}
public void setDate_time(Timestamp date_time) {
    this.date_time = date_time;
}
public int getRating() {
    return rating;
}
public void setRating(int rating) {
    this.rating = rating;
}
public int getParentscat_id() {
    return parentscat_id;
}
public void setParentscat_id(int parentscat_id) {
    this.parentscat_id = parentscat_id;
}
public String getParentscat_name() {
    return parentscat_name;
}
public void setParentscat_name(String parentscat_name) {
    this.parentscat_name = parentscat_name;
}
public String getThumCoverImag() {
    return thumCoverImag;
}
public void setThumCoverImag(String thumCoverImag) {
    this.thumCoverImag = thumCoverImag;
}
public String getFilePath() {
    return filePath;
}
public void setFilePath(String filePath) {
    this.filePath = filePath;
}   
}
```

BooksInfoDAO.java

```
package com.sreejonee.books;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.sreejonee.db.ConnectionFactory;
import com.sreejonee.db.DBConnector;

public class BooksInfoDAO {
 Connection connection;
 Statement stmt;
 private int noOfRecords;
private static Connection getConnection() 
        throws SQLException, 
            ClassNotFoundException 
{
    Connection con = ConnectionFactory.
            getInstance().getConnection();
    System.out.println("connected!");
    return con;
}

public List<BooksInfo> viewAllBooksInfo(int offset, int noOfRecords) {
    String query = "select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from library ORDER by date_time DESC limit"+ offset + ", " + noOfRecords;

    List<BooksInfo> bookslist = new ArrayList<BooksInfo>();
    BooksInfo books = null;

    try {
        connection = getConnection();
        stmt = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            books = new BooksInfo();
            books.setBook_id(rs.getInt("book_id"));
            books.setBook_details(rs.getString("book_details"));
            books.setBookName(rs.getString("bookName"));
            books.setWriterName(rs.getString("writerName"));
            books.setDate_time(rs.getTimestamp("date_time"));
            books.setParentscat_id(rs.getInt("parentscat_id"));
            books.setParentscat_name(rs.getString("parentscat_name"));
            books.setFilename(rs.getString("filename"));
            books.setFilePath(rs.getString("filePath"));
            books.setRating(rs.getInt("rating"));
            books.setThumCoverImag(rs.getString("thumCoverImag"));

            bookslist.add(books);
        }
        rs.close();

        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()");
        if (rs.next())
            this.noOfRecords = rs.getInt(1);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return bookslist;
}

public int getNoOfRecords() {
    return noOfRecords;
}
}
```

Servlet:
BooksInfoServlet.java

```
package com.sreejonee.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import com.sreejonee.books.BooksInfo;
import com.sreejonee.books.BooksInfoDAO;


@WebServlet("/BooksInfoServlet")
public class BooksInfoServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public BooksInfoServlet() {
    super();        
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    int page = 1;
    int recordsPerPage = 5;
    if(request.getParameter("page") != null)
        page = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page"));
    BooksInfoDAO booksInfoDAO = new BooksInfoDAO();
    List<BooksInfo> bookslist = booksInfoDAO.viewAllBooksInfo((page-1)*recordsPerPage, recordsPerPage);
    int noOfRecords = booksInfoDAO.getNoOfRecords();
    int noOfPages = (int) Math.ceil(noOfRecords * 1.0 / recordsPerPage);
    request.setAttribute("booksList", bookslist);
    request.setAttribute("noOfPages", noOfPages);
    request.setAttribute("currentPage", page);
    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("user.jsp");
    view.forward(request, response);
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

}
}
```

JSP page:

```
<c:forEach var="books" items="${bookslist}">

<div id="${books.filename}" class="single_midlecontent_component">
    <div class="socialicon_on_post">
        <h4>
            <i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="title_of_post ">
        <a href="#" class="media-left"> 
            <img class="media-object" src="${books.getFilePath()+File.separator+books.getThumCoverImag()}" alt="...">
        </a>
        <h5 class="media-body ">
            <span><a href="">${books.getBookName()}</a></span>
        </h5>
        <h5 class="media-body ">
            <span>by <a href="">${books.getWriterName()}</a></span>
        </h5>
        <p class="date_time  media-body">${books.getDate_time()}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="body_of_post">
        <p>${books.getBook_details()}</p>
        <img src="" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
    </div>
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
    <div class="download_book">
        <form action="DownloadFileServlet" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="filename" value="${books.getFilename()}">
            <div>
                <input type="hidden" name="parentscat_name" value="${books.getParentscat_name()}">
            </div>
            <div class="download_button">
                <input class="btn btn-default " type="submit" value="Download">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom_of_post"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: please give just the minimal info required. in your case, it seems to me that this is just the final SQL statement that will be executed. otherwise people trying to help you loose a lot of their time reading unneeded stuff, and trying to figure out what they have to read and what not.

Comment: Just do `System.out.println(query);` and verify if whatever query the DB actually obtained looks all right?

Answer (score 1):

I can see two errors here.

*First one:*

```
String query = "select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from library ORDER by date_time DESC limit"+ offset + ", " + noOfRecords;
```

There is a space missing after `limit` -- the way you wrote it, it will generate `... limit10, 5`.

*Second one:*

I think the caller of `viewAllBooksInfo()` gives a wrong `offset` argument. Based on the error, I assume that `offset` is `-10` which is illegal because the arguments to the `limit` clause in MySQL need to be [non-negative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367693/negative-limit-offset-in-mysql).

In your updated question, you show this code:

```
if(request.getParameter("page") != null)
    page = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page"));
BooksInfoDAO booksInfoDAO = new BooksInfoDAO();
List<BooksInfo> bookslist = booksInfoDAO.viewAllBooksInfo((page-1)*recordsPerPage, recordsPerPage);
```

Obviously, because `recordsPerPage` is `5`, and `offset` is `-10`, `page` seems to be `-1`. You have not shown the Code for the page which calls the `BooksInfoServlet`, but I guess you have entered `-1` as the requested page number there.

Answer (score 0):

You should have looked yourself before asking this question. It is expected from you that you should first try to remove these error yourself.

If you would look into the error stack, it says:
**"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-10, 5' at line 1"**

If you can look carefully, the limit options are *"-10, 5"*.  Limit arguments in MySQL should be non-negative.

And in **BooksInfoDAO.java** code:

```
public List<BooksInfo> viewAllBooksInfo(int offset, int noOfRecords) {
    String query = "select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from library ORDER by date_time DESC limit"+ offset + ", " + noOfRecords;
    ...
```

you are missing a space between the limit clause and the offset parameter.